# Weird "expr:Division by Zero" output when running through a while loop

Tags: bash, loops, shell

Greeting
I am currently developing a function thaT converts each decimal to binary without using awk sed printf xxd od perl ibase, obase , bc
However, the function managed to convert into decimal to binary but for some reason, it is outputting the "expr:Division by Zero" at the end of the converted binary

I have tried to remove expr and set as a normal formula but it distributed another error so i have no choice to stuck with this since it is the closet thing that converts decimal to binary

```
for i in $d do #$d is the decimal
num = $d #decimal number
div = 128 #it is the power number (we should start dividing by 128)
sec = 0 #to run the loop 8 times 
while [[ $seq -ne 9 ]] 
do 
    bin=`expr $num / $div`
    echo -n "$bin" # we can add the replacing x and space here 
    rem=`expr $num % $div` # gets the remainder
    div=$(expr $div / 2) #to get the decreasing power of 2 
    num=$rem #next the num should be equal to the remainder 
    sec=$(sec + 1) 
done
done 

#OUTPUT
Output :  11111000expr:division by zero
```

Any hint will be much appreciated

Comment: By setting `sec` to 0 and looping until `sec` is 9, that's looping 9 times, not 8.

Comment: @sj95126 Thanks for noticing, I got it down to 8 and unfortunately, the output is clumped together instead of separating each converted binary into its own column.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of things wrong here, starting with simple syntax. If you want to convert from decimal representation to binary representation using pure `bash`, you can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

dec=123456 # for example
bin=
n=$dec
while ((n)); do
    bin=$((n & 1))$bin
    ((n >>= 1))
done

echo "$dec(decimal) = ${bin:-0}(binary)"
```

This should work for all non-negative integers which can be represented in 63 bits (unless your `bash` version is very old).